# page not loading react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load page using react router. but page is not loading.

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Menu from './Menu';
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Registration from './Customer/Registration'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Menu/>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

i am using menu.js file for my menu.  Please check my menu.js file

menu.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Registration from './Customer/Registration';
export default class Menu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
 <div>

    <Router>

      <ul className="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">

        <li className="active treeview menu-open">
          <a href="#">
            <i className="fa fa-dashboard" /> <span>Customer</span>
            <span className="pull-right-container">
              <i className="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" />
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul className="treeview-menu">
            <li>
                <Link to="/Registration" className="nav-link">Registration</Link>
                </li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
              <Route  path='Customer/Registration' component={Registration} />
          </Switch>
        </li>

      </ul>
     </Router>

</div>

        )
    }
}
```

this is the folder structure in my project 
[image]

i am unable to create demo. if u can guess the issue with this project.

page is loading inside the leftmenu. i need to load it middle of the page
[image]

Comment: are you running this on a server or host?

Comment: running locally. http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Do you mean you don't see anything at all in the browser? Or can you see the header and footer at least? Also, try `<Route  path='/Registration'`

Comment: no template is loading. but when i click 'Registration link'  registration page not loading. localhost:3000/Registration

Comment: If you fix the Route's `path`, it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-voice-sfcsu

Comment: now page content load in the left menu (menu.js) . not in the template body

Comment: Where is the template body? You've put the Switch inside of sidebar.

Comment: i added image now. pls check my question

Comment: i want to my Registration page content to middle of the page   <div id="root">. but now its loading in menu area

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do but you have to declare your router in a top level to be able to render your content in a different view where you are clicking the link. You're declaring the route in the same view and that's why. Check it out https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6517/react-router-tutorial

Comment: how i use menu.js file. do i need to menu.js file content into app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **Link** and **Route**. Can you please check the URL for Registration? 
I think your route should be look like below.

```
<Route  path='/Registration' component={Registration} />
```

Comment: Registration.js is in the Customer folder. can u check my folder structure . i checked ur solution. but not working

Comment: Route is responsible to render component UI when a location matches the route’s path. Path is not depends of the file location.

Comment: now page content load in the left menu (menu.js) . not in the template body

Comment: i found the issue. issue is  <Switch>
              <Route  path='Customer/Registration' component={Registration} />
          </Switch> inside the menu. it should place after the menu.